# Проблема в авторизации яндекс диск с помощью retrofit2

Tags: java, android, android-studio, retrofit, retrofit2

Изучаю Retrofit2, пытаюсь получить токен Yandex disk, в документации яндекса написано, чтобы получить токен необходимо для начала подтвердить разрешения пользователя и получить код. В документации об этом написано:

> Получение токена в обмен на код, извлеченный из URL:
>
> Приложение направляет пользователя на страницу Яндекс.OAuth, где он может
>   разрешить доступ к своим данным.
>
> Пользователь разрешает доступ приложению.
>
> Яндекс.OAuth перенаправляет пользователя на адрес, указанный в поле
>   Callback URL при регистрации приложения. Код подтверждения (или
>   описание ошибки) передается в параметре URL перенаправления.
>
> Приложение получает адрес перенаправления и извлекает код
>   подтверждения.
>
> Приложение отправляет POST-запрос с кодом.
>
> Яндекс.OAuth возвращает токен в теле ответа.

**Получаю код так:**

**Имеется сервис, создающий синглтоном экземпляр ретрофита. В странном методе пук:) получаю этот самый код:**

```
public class NetworkService {
    private static NetworkService mInstance;
    private static final String BASE_URL = "https://oauth.yandex.ru";
    private Retrofit mRetrofit;
    private static final String ID = "здесь мой id";
    private static final String PASSWORD = "здесь мой пароль";
    private static final String CALLBACK_URI = "здесь колбэк";

    private NetworkService() {
        HttpLoggingInterceptor interceptor = new HttpLoggingInterceptor();
        interceptor.setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY);
        Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
                .setLenient()
                .create();
        OkHttpClient.Builder client = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
                .addInterceptor(interceptor);

        mRetrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(gson))
                .client(client.build())
                .build();

    }

    public static NetworkService getInstance() {
        if (mInstance == null) {
            mInstance = new NetworkService();
        }
        return mInstance;
    }

    public ApiService getJSONApi() {
        return mRetrofit.create(ApiService.class);
    }


    public static void puk() {
        Call<AccessCodeYandex> call = NetworkService.getInstance().getJSONApi().getToken( ID);

        call.enqueue(new Callback<AccessCodeYandex>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<AccessCodeYandex> call, Response<AccessCodeYandex> response) {
                System.out.println();
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<AccessCodeYandex> call, Throwable t) {
                System.out.println();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

**Интерфейс для rest запросов:**

```
public interface ApiService {
    @POST("/authorize?response_type=code")
    @FormUrlEncoded
    Call<AccessCodeYandex> getToken1(@Field("client_id") String client_id);
}
```

**Ну и модель для возврата ответа:**

```
@NoArgsConstructor
@Getter
@Setter
public class AccessCodeYandex {
    @SerializedName("code")
    @Expose
    private String code;
    @SerializedName("state")
    @Expose
    private String state;
}
```

Попадаю в **Failure** с ошибкой:

> com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: java.lang.IllegalStateException:
>   Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was STRING at line 1 column 1 path $

**Вот так запускаю страницу для подтверждения. Как сделать ридерект с полученным кодом в приложение?**

```
 private void getView() {
        AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        alert.setTitle("Title here");

        WebView wv = new WebView(this);
        wv.loadUrl("https://oauth.yandex.ru/authorize?response_type=code&client_id=мой айди");
        wv.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
            @Override
            public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
                view.loadUrl(url);

                return true;
            }
        });
        alert.setView(wv);
        alert.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                dialog.dismiss();
            }
        });
        alert.show();
    }
```

Comment: Вам приходит не тот JSON который вы ожидаете. Выведите в логи что отвечает сервер и приложите в вопрос. Прологгировать можно через `LoggingInterceptor`. А, он у вас даже есть, значит просто покажите что сервер отвечает.

Comment: @ЮрийСПб добавил логи

Comment: @ЮрийСПб весь лог не вмещается

Comment: @ЮрийСПб остальной тут https://hello-site.ru/share/dfsd/

Comment: Я по странным ссылкам не хожу) Найдите в логе собственно тело ответа сервера. То что у вас сейчас в вопросе - заголовки, они не нужны в данном случае.

Comment: @ЮрийСПб обновил. это то,что пришло последнее

Comment: Ну, вам приходит в ответ HTML страница с формой входа. Вы, похоже, неправильно поняли как проходит авторизация. Вам надо сначала запустить браузер/webView по адресу авторизации яндекса. Там юзер авторизовывается, вбивая логин-пароль, после чего браузер редиректит юзера. Редирект перехватывает ваше приложение, вытаскивает из адреса редиректа код и только на этот этапе через ретрофит делает запрос к API яндекса на обмен кода на токен.

Comment: @ЮрийСПб сделал, получилось показать пользователю страницу для подтверждения, а как теперь код вернуть приложению? обновил вопрос

Comment: В зависимости от того как вы страницу открываете с авторизацией. Если как у вас - в WebView, то надо в методе `shouldOverrideUrlLoading` отслеживать адрес открытия и из него код брать. Если запускаете браузер обычный, то надо `deepLinking` использовать.